# Custom shape rows with background images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make some responsive rows in HTML & CSS with a custom shape. I was trying to follow [this thread](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/help-with-skewed-div/201556), but I can't make it work using background images. This is the final result I'm trying to build, but I'm having issues setting the background image:
[Result, but using I need background images instead solid colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3IPh.png)

I've copied the example in the thread and made [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-dhawan-n77y6d?file=/styles.css), as you can see, I can set the background image of the first div, but setting it in the rest of the divs is showing an undesirable result.

What is the best way to make this work?

Comment: have you tried using `clip-path` yet?

Comment: @vnm As I put in the post, that didn't work

Comment: @tacoshy How can I achieve the same result using clip-path? I need the divs to be close from each other, so using clip-path would leave an empty blank space between each row

Comment: See my Answer, a negative margin will attech the elements to each other without gap.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be using clip-path. To ensure the elemnts attach smoothly and not cut away parts of the content you should use a `container` and an `inner` element.

The background-color/background-image should be used on the `container` while the `inner` element contains the content.

Then you add a fixed `padding` `top` and `bottom` to the container (50px in my case) and use `clip-path` to cut away parts of the `padding` of the container.

Last but not least to attch the element without gap on to each other you use a negative `margin-top` equal to the `padding`

```css
/* change the value off this variable as you like */
:root {
  --clip-height: 50px;
}

/* clipping & gapless aligning */
.container {
  padding-bottom: var(--clip-height);
  padding-top: var(--clip-height);
  margin-top: calc(var(--clip-height) * -1);
}

.container:nth-child(odd) {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% var(--clip-height), 100% calc(100% - var(--clip-height)), 0 100%);
}

.container:nth-child(even) {
  clip-path: polygon(0 var(--clip-height), 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - var(--clip-height)));
}


/* For Demonstration purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.inner {
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.container:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background-color: green;
}

.container:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```